# Changed the functions.php file for a WordPress site, now the whole site lost its "theme"

Tags: wordpress, url, directory

Ok, I will try to explain as best as I know how...I have two domains under one hosting account.  (granitechristianacademy.org and gofbc.com)  I created the hosting account with granitechristianacademy.org first, then added gofbc.com in a subdirectory "/FBC".
I was attempting to figure out how to change the way the browser displays granitechristianacademy.org/FBC when I type in gofbc.com.  In attempting to fix this, I changed the two URLs on the wordpress settings.  I had the location of the wordpress directory as /FBC, and the Site URL as gofbc.com.  I swapped the two, my site (gofbc.com) displayed correctly from the front-end, but would not let me login to the dashboard. 
So I followed the Wordpress directions to change the two manually by changing the functions.php file of the active theme and adding

"update_option('siteurl','http://example.com/blog');
update_option('home','http://example.com/blog');"

after the initial

Comment: wow .. that is really hard to read .. can you break this up somewhat. That'll make it easier for everyone to read and hopefully help. Just a friendly suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've put yourself in a very sticky situation. If you have access to the databases, you can verify that the URLs are all correct within the **wp_options** table. You'll want to look for any entries within that table that contain a URL to your site, and just check they're all correct (yes, there are a couple).

Aside from that, you can try re-activating your website themes or saving the permalinks settings again. For some reason, refreshing permalinks is a magical solution to a lot more problems than you'd think.

If none of those work, you're in a bit of strife. I'd highly recommend taking out a second hosting account, or at the very least finding a hosting plan that allows for multiple domains. While it may cost more, the alternative is a massive headache and many more hours of your time.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your reply.  I have gone under the wp_options table, and only have "blog_id", "option_name", "option_value", and "autoload"...didn't see anything with the URL...                            I can't try re-activating the themes or saving permalinks because when I swapped the URLs, it kicked me off and would not let me sign in.  On another note, is it not possible to fix the URL issue? My Business hosting plan with 1&1 allows for multiple domains...

Comment: I figured out the database (new to that) and changed the Home and Site URL values, not sure how long it will take for changes to take effect.

Comment: Site works from the front end...any ideas why I still can't log in?